# git create branch in my repo that is not spun off from existing branches

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a repo that I forked from another repo.

Let us call my repo as `origin` and the parent repo as `upstream`

I regularly work in my `origin` repo's master branch and when ready, I submit the same via pull request to `upstream`.

Recently, I did a lot of work in my `origin` repo's master branch and created a PR to `upstream` but since the work was quite a bit, it ran into several issues related to conflicts, tests etc etc.

Now another important task came up that I need to work upon.

But when I try to create `git checkout -b branch_for_new_work`, it takes all the changes from the `master` branch of `origin` repo. How do I create a branch whose code-base aligns with the `remote` repo's master branch and not my `origin` repo's master branch? (I now know that its a good practice to create branches for such work and not pollute the master).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I create a branch whose code-base aligns with the remote repo's master branch and not my origin repo's master branch?

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout -b <new-branch> upstream/master     # create a new branch with upstream/master history
```

If you want to create a Pull request where **base:** upstream/master and **compare:** origin/master then, always pull `upstream/master` into your origin/master to avoid Conflicts.

---

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'new_branch' at the same time

Make sure you have fetched your remote (`upstream` here).

---

**Alternate Solution:** Create a new branch `new_branch` from your current branch then `reset` local `new_branch` with `upstream/master`

```
$ git remote -v              # make sure your remote name is 'upstream' or else

$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout -b new_branch

$ git reset --hard upstream/master
```

Comment: I am getting an error as follows:

`git checkout -b new_branch upstream/master`

fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'new_branch' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/master' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: Thanks, `git fetch upstream` fixed the issue followed by `git checkout -b new_branch upstream/master`